# Error during Keycloak realm import "Provided realm contains authenticator config with null alias."

Tags: jboss, keycloak, quarkus, redhat

While trying to import a Keycloak realm from Keycloak 9.0.2 to Keycloak 22, a following error occurs:

2023-09-27 19:53:30,734 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (import_export) mode
2023-09-27 19:53:30,735 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Provided realm contains authenticator config with null alias. It should be resolved by adding alias to the authenticator config before exporting the realm.

Realm export has been successful, but import for some reason doesn't work. Error description does tell me what to do, but I don't know where to do it and how.

I appreciate anyones help.

Steps to reproduce:
`docker exec -it <containerID> /bin/bash`
`cd /opt/keycloak`
`./bin/kc.sh import --dir <folder_with_exported_data>/`

I followed official Keycloak documentation, but to no avail.